Historical manhwa where the female lead has a subspace/medical kit
Looking for a historical manhwa where the female lead has a subspace/medical kit. She can get guns, medicine and other modern equipment. The subspace or medical kit doesn't run out.

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead? Also, you added the [time-travel] tag to the question, so how does time travel factor into the story?

The female lead was originally from a modern world. I don't recall her hair color. All I can recall is that she had it behind her ear. That's where she would touch to access it.

As noted by Talin, this is likely The Divine Doctor by Yangshiliu (original novel) and Aquarius and Keai (comic authors).


With a clap of thunder, Feng Yuheng, a god at both Western and traditional Chinese medicine, transmigrates to the time of the Shun Dynasty, into the body of an abused teenaged girl. You wish to kill me? A single stab of my scalpel will paralyze half your body! My pharmacy from the past life is always with me, and fame and fortune rest within the palm of my hand. Even the Emperor wishes to be my acquaintance! And you, you roguish prince... are you toying with me?

She is former medical military, and died in a helicopter accident. The access to her pharmacy is through her Phoenix birthmark, though, not her ear or her hair.

I think it might be “the divine doctor” you can read it on webnovel.com

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should add a description to show how it matches the question.

https://www.webnovel.com/comic/the-divine-doctor_13137684906876901 but I can't access it right now.
